# NSUrlDomainError code -1002 "unsupported URL"

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I am trying to use [this](https://github.com/vitoziv/VIMediaCache) library to enable caching my videos. And I receive this error:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=4185c72c-252e-4019-8c1c-e30b4ccbe597/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=4185c72c-252e-4019-8c1c-e30b4ccbe597/, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
>       "LocalDataTask <85069315-C50B-404F-86D8-548ED16B9103>.<1>

The code that is causing this problem is:

```
  VIResourceLoaderManager *resourceLoaderManager = [VIResourceLoaderManager new];
  self.resourceLoaderManager = resourceLoaderManager;
  AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [resourceLoaderManager playerItemWithURL:url];
  return [self initWithPlayerItem:playerItem frameUpdater:frameUpdater];
}
```

However if I remove the lines added for this library to work, then it works perfectly( without caching ) like this:

```
AVPlayerItem* item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
return [self initWithPlayerItem:item frameUpdater:frameUpdater];
```

The url in question is `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/app_domain/o/ed8f47cc-e9ee-43d0-848e-06edaaeaab70.mp4?alt=media&token=4185c72c-252e-4019-8c1c-e30b4ccbe597`

I have changed the url a little bit for security. But it plays in browser and as I said it works well without the caching code.

Comment: Could you please show more of your code that is using the library? I cannot reproduce your issue with a valid Firebase video URL and the code you've posted so far.

Comment: @BenW [this](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/video_player/video_player/ios/Classes/FLTVideoPlayerPlugin.m) is the code for a flutter plugin named video_player. I am trying to add cache support to it. I am making these changes to the `initWithUrl` method.

Answer (score 0):

According to error description, you have extra slash `/` at the end of your url:

`NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=4185c72c-252e-4019-8c1c-e30b4ccbe597/` < extra slash

Comment: Actually I added the slash later just to check if that could be the problem.The error is occurring even when there is no slash at end.

Answer (score 0):

Url that you are requested, returninig 404 Not found!

Answer (score 0):

I imported that library into the Flutter plugin you mentioned and was able to successfully load a video from a valid Firebase URL. I added some logging via mediaDownloader:didReceiveData: in the VIResourceLoadingRequestWorker class and it looks like the caching is happening properly.

Updated initWithURL:frameUpdater: method to look like this:

```
- (instancetype)initWithURL:(NSURL*)url frameUpdater:(FLTFrameUpdater*)frameUpdater
{
    VIResourceLoaderManager* resourceLoaderManager = [[VIResourceLoaderManager alloc] init];

// Uncomment this to test with an empty cache, so the manager will re-cache
//    [resourceLoaderManager cleanCache];

    AVPlayerItem* item = [resourceLoaderManager playerItemWithURL:url];

    self = [self initWithPlayerItem:item frameUpdater:frameUpdater];

    if (self)
    {
        self.resourceLoaderManager = resourceLoaderManager;
        self.resourceLoaderManager.delegate = self;
    }

    return self;
}
```

- See if by any chance, the above changes work for you, but it seems like it might be something else.
- Try your code with a simpler test URL from somewhere and see if it is indeed something to do with the actual URL (doubtful, since I had success with the other Firebase video URL and you said yours definitely works in a browser)
- Add a tag for Flutter to your question, so someone more familiar with that technology may see it and be able to help.